# Log4j настройка логирования ошибок

Tags: java, log4j

Как можно настроить чтоб с консоли все warn, error, fatal писались в error.log?

```
log4j.rootLogger=console, stdout 
log4j.logger.AUTH=INFO, auth
log4j.logger.LOG=INFO, file
log4j.logger.ERROR=WARN, error


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} {%p} %c{1}.%M:%L = %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.auth=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.auth.File=${catalina.home}/logs/auth.log
log4j.appender.auth.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.auth.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.auth.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.auth.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.error=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.error.File=${catalina.home}/logs/error.log
log4j.appender.error.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.error.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.error.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout error

log4j.appender.error.Threshold=WARN

Comment: не получилось. нет в логе ошибок